# Python: Comparing values in two lists

Tags: python, list, variables, while-loop

I've really tried looking all over for solutions to my problem but haven't been successful in finding anything. If someone else has already asked this question, I apologize. Onto the problem.

I have two lists in with values to be compared to each other. I have tried the following option.

```
list1 = [1,3,5,7,9]
list2 = [200,2]
x = 0
n = 0
y = 0

while x <= 9:
    if list1[y] >= list2[n]:
        print('TRUE')
        x = x + 1
        y = y + 1
        if y > 4:
            y = 0
            n = n + 1
    else:
        print('FALSE')
        x = x + 1
        y = y + 1
        if y > 4:
            y = 0
            n = n + 1
```

The only problem is, instead of the variables in place, I need to iterate through a list of values.

So instead, I would like the code to look something like this:

```
x = 0
n = [0,1]
y = [0,3]
z = len(n) + len(y) - 1

while x <= z:
    if list1[y] >= list2[n]:
        print('TRUE')
        x = x + 1

    else:
        print('FALSE')
        x = x + 1
```

Where n and y are index values of the numbers that I want to compare.

This does not work for me and I'm really not sure how else to do this.

Edit: I didn't think I had to explain everything by text since I included two sets of code. The first set of code works and it shows exactly what I am trying to do. The second is what I want it to do.

Broken down further I want to know if list1[0]>=list2[0], followed by list1[3]>=list2[0], followed by list1[0]>=list2[1], followed by list1[3]>=list2[1]. The outputs that I expect are in the code I provided.

Apologies if I wasn't clear before. I need to call specific index positions that I will have in a separate list. This is the problem that I tried to outline in the second code.

Comment: What does "to be compared to each other" mean? Please explain when you expect the output to be True.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is this actually for? Is it merely a puzzle of some sort?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to explain the problem more clearly. "I have two lists in with values to be compared to each other." This is effectively never a complete description of the problem. What kind of comparisons need to be performed? Which values in the first list should be compared to what values in the second list? *What should happen* depending on the comparison result?

Comment: If you look at the code, I am using comparison operators. The output will be true if list1 val is greater than list 2 val. This is a computation biology problem I am having. I am just trying to make this super simple at first and then building up.

Comment: Are those TRUE/FALSE prints actually what you need in the end?

Comment: If the first code *"shows exactly what I am trying to do"*, why did you say it *"kind of works"*? The latter means that there's something wrong with it and thus we can't learn from it what you're trying to do.

Comment: The TRUE/FALSE prints are just for the time being. I will eventually replace them with something else, but they satisfy the objective of trying to get the code to work for now.

Comment: I meant the first code kinda works for what I am trying to accomplish. The problem is that I am dealing with thousands of lines of data and I'm not able to count them at such large numbers. Ultimately I need a way to automate this, which is what I am trying to do in the second code.

Comment: As far as I understand, basically you are trying to take an element of list2 1 at a time and compare with all the elements of list1 and print if list1 elemtent i greater than list 2, right?

Comment: @DivijMahajan almost correct, I am trying to take an element of list2 and compare it to one or more elements in list 1.

Comment: MarkPellicle: Not "almost" correct. What @DivijMahajan described is *exactly* what your reference code does, and since you basically declared that to be the specification and didn't otherwise provide one, that's exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here it is again what I am trying to do ```n = [0,1]
y = [0,3] list1[0]>=list2[0], followed by list1[3]>=list2[0], followed by list1[0]>=list2[1], followed by list1[3]>=list2[1]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think now get what you are trying to do.
First, there are two lists of "raw" data:

```
list1 = [1,3,5,7,9]
list2 = [200,2]
```

Then, there are two sets of "indices of interest":

```
y = [0, 3] # indices of interest for list1
n = [0, 1] # indices of interest for list2
```

I think the following can achieve what you want:

```
product = [(index1, index2) for index2 in n for index1 in y] #cartesian product 
for index1, index2 in product:
    if list1[index1] >= list2[index2]:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

Or if the cartesian product is not wanted, simply do it within nested loops:

```
for index2 in n: 
    for index1 in y:
        if list1[index1] >= list2[index2]:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
```